# Network unstable between Turtlebot and workstation

Tags: ros, turtlebot, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, i have a problem with the wireless connection between Turtlebot and my workstation (Dell XPS with Intel Centrino Wireless 6230, ROS-electric).
If i launch the turtlebot_teleop on my workstation the network is stable but if i try to launch something like rviz or image_view the network falls.
Initially the bit-rate was 2 Mbit/s while now is about 40 kbit/s without modify nothing. However, the network is always falling.
I have tried to change workstation with a old acer and the network was slowly but stable!
How can i solve this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44553/network-unstable-between-turtlebot-and-workstation/) by [Yuri](https://answers.ros.org/users/2892/yuri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not hard to saturate your network connection when streaming things like raw images and point clouds (which you may be visualizing with image_view or rviz). There are a few things you could try:

- When subscribing to images, use one of the compressed transports (compressed or theora)
- Try throttling point clouds on the machine that publishes them. According to my back of the envelope calculation, the point cloud from a kinect creates about 140MB/s of data, which on its own could saturate a 802.11n link. You can throttle topics with [topic_tools/throttle](http://ros.org/wiki/topic_tools/throttle).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3